# import excel to sql server 2014 express

Tags: sql-server-express, import-from-excel

There seems to have been many discussions on this but I couldn't find something specific to what I am looking for. I am trying to import excel to sql server 2014 express edition.

I already try it using Import and Export Wizard and it success but I want make scheduling because i'm going to import excel to sql every week. From what I've learn it can be done with SSIS but from this [site](https://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/Microsoft-SSIS-SQL-Server-Integration-Services) i read that SQL server Express doesn't provide SSIS.

Can anyone tell me another way to make scheduling import excel to sql server 2014 express edition. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You *can't* schedule SSIS tasks in Express because you need Agent and/or a licenced version of SSIS; which Express edition does not have. You could look into using `OPENROWSET` , `OPENDATASOURCE` or a linked server, and then using Windows Scheduler to run the task on the SQL Server.

Comment: Side note, The Express Editions of SQL are free, so why are you still using 2014 which is only in extended support. You can upgrade to the latest version (2019) at no cost.

Comment: from this [site](https://community.denodo.com/kb/en/view/document/Accessing%20Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Linked%20Servers?category=Northbound%20Connections) said that SQL server Express edition also doesn't provide linked server. But i'll try using OPENROWSER or OPENDATASOURCE like what you said. @Larnu

Comment: can you give the links to do it with OPENROWSET , OPENDATASOURCE, and using Windows Scheduler to run the task on the SQL Server? Thank you @Larnu

Comment: I'm using the 2014 version because the campus doesn't allow other versions @Larnu

Comment: @Sanada that website is wrong. It states *"Only SQL Server Developer and SQL Server Enterprise versions support Linked Servers."* And I know that isn't true as I'm connected to a standard edition instance with linked Servers. I'm pretty confident SQL Server Express supports linked servers too.

Comment: As for links, the documentation for SQL Server is very expansive, I would suggest starting on the relevant documentation pages for `OPENROWSET`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243285/discussion-between-sarada-and-larnu).

Answer (score 0):

As SQL server Express 2014 does not have agent Jobs, You need to rely on other tools. I would suggest to have a Stored procedure to [import data from excel file](https://www.eternussolutions.com/2015/03/31/data-import-simplified-excel-to-sql-using-stored-procedure/) to tables. You can write simple .NET app that execute the SP. Then you can configure the .NET app in windows task scheduler to run weekly basis.

Comment: But the data from excel must be import to SQL server Express 2014. Can i still do it with the way you suggest? @Amila Fernando

Comment: Yes,  

Windows task scheduler execute .NET app -> .NET app call Stored Procedure -> Stored Procedure read the excel file, extract data and insert to SQL Server.

Only difference from SSIS+Agent job is that you are using Windows scheduler to run this job.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if can't use sql server agent or SSIS the only option I can think of is to write a script to import your data.
You can use C# to create a .net framework console application and schedule it with Windows task schedule.
Here is an   [article with a code](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-Excel-data-to-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)  that you can use as a basis to import data from excel to your sql server database.

It is not the optimal solution, but given your limitations and your purpose it may work.